# RxAndroid issue with retrofit?

Tags: java, android, casting, rx-java, rx-android

I'm having a cast problem inside the subscribe method, i don't know why the new Observer is giving this issue.

```
 Observable<GradeModel> getGrade = retrofit
                .create(GradeService.class)
                .getGrade()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(model -> {
                    // transform model
                    DecimalFormat grades = (DecimalFormat) model.getGrades();
                    return grades;
                })
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<DecimalFormat>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onError method of observer");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(DecimalFormat grades) {
                        mainPresenter.setListGrades(grades);
                    }
                });
```

> Required:
>   rx.Observable
>   
>   Found:
>   rx.Subscription

Comment: SafeSubscriber implements Observer, not Observable.  Is this what you intended to cast to? Why cast at all BTW?

Comment: I'm new on rxJava. So i don't know what BTW means.

Comment: BTW means "by the way" and was probably used a thousand years before rxjava. ;-)

Comment: :D ah ok. I don't want cast anything. I just want take the data with this, and i saw in some tutorials that. Those cast errors are from rx classes not me. So i don't know why my observer dont work, i tryied change for new Subscriber(){ANONYMOUS CLASS} and still same error.

Comment: "Those errors are not me"? They are caused by you taking a returned object from rxjava and trying to cast it into something it's not. The subscribe method does not return anything that implements Observable. So, while you could simply remove the cast, that you say you don't have but it's clearly there on the first line of your code, it would probably better to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: ah of course. That... i forgot that there rsrs. Ok, i erased that, and now is giving an error: required Observable, found Subscription.

Comment: If you just remove the cast but still declare your variable as Observable, then yes you still have the same issue - trying to assign a variable to an object of a different type. Casting is a way of saying "hey I KNOW" this object implements Observable so please just assign it. That failed because, well it's not true. Without the cast you're saying that the object already implicitly is an Observable, which is also not true. Declare your variable as a Subscriber or Observer.

Comment: Subscription worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Up until `.subscribe(...)` it is an `Observable`. However after subscribing it returns a `Subscription` instance which can be used to cancel the subscription.

The exception occurs because you are casting this `Subscription` back into an `Observable` although they are completely unrelated.

Without knowing your intentions with that variable it is hard to say what the correct code would be.